# Slow internet on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, internet

I have a Vaio FitFlip Laptop and I dual booted it with Windows and Ubuntu.

The problem is, when I'm in another room where the wireless signal is not really strong, the Internet connection goes really slow and disconnects automatically a lot and asks for the wireless password.

When I'm in the same room where the wireless router's signal is stronger, it doesn't seem to have that problem.

This doesn't happen when I'm using Windows, so I think it is related to Ubuntu.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: having the same problem lately. I'm sure not because of the internet or wireless router, my tablet can surf web the same time and very fast while laptop internet... slow